# Form field calculations

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I have a working form but i need it to email a value which is text only (doesn't include the numerical value). If there's any easier way to do this please can you help.

Here's the js fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/qeSZR/83/

Basically when you click on corporate it calculates the value and changes it to 3500 and when you click on private it changes it to 1800. The problem i have is that when you mail this, i have a field that says "client type" which includes "1800: Private" or "3500: Corporate" as its sent value. I don't want the numbers in it i'd rather just have the client type = private or corporate. Please help :) - thank you!

Here is the code:

HTML

```
     <form action="mailer.php" data-validate="parsley" method="post">
             <div class="driver-list">
                <p>
                <h2>Driver 1:</h2>
                Name <span class="red">*</span>&nbsp; <input name="cf_driver1" data-required="true" type="text" class="form-text" />
                Cellphone <span class="red">*</span>&nbsp; <input name="cf_cell1" data-required="true" type="text" class="form-text" />
                Email <span class="red">*</span>&nbsp; <input name="cf_email1" data-required="true" data-type="email" type="text" class="form-text" /></p>
                <h2>Driver 2:</h2>
                Name <span class="red">*</span>&nbsp; <input name="cf_driver2" data-required="true" type="text" class="form-text" />
                Cellphone <span class="red">*</span>&nbsp; <input name="cf_cell2" data-required="true" type="text" class="form-text" />
                Email <span class="red">*</span>&nbsp; <input name="cf_email2" data-required="true" data-type="email" type="text" class="form-text" /></p>
                <h2>Driver 3:</h2>
                Name <span class="red">*</span>&nbsp; <input name="cf_driver3" data-required="true" type="text" class="form-text" />
                Cellphone <span class="red">*</span>&nbsp; <input name="cf_cell3" data-required="true" type="text" class="form-text" />
                Email <span class="red">*</span>&nbsp; <input name="cf_email3" data-required="true" data-type="email" type="text" class="form-text" /></p>
                <h2>Driver 4:</h2>
                Name <span class="red">*</span>&nbsp; <input name="cf_driver4" data-required="true" type="text" class="form-text" />
                Cellphone <span class="red">*</span>&nbsp; <input name="cf_cell4" data-required="true" type="text" class="form-text" />
                Email <span class="red">*</span>&nbsp; <input name="cf_email4" data-required="true" data-type="email" type="text" class="form-text" /></p>
              </div>
          <div class="vertical-space"></div><p><h2>Entry Type<span class="red">*</span></h2></p>
          <select name="cf_client_type" id="cf_client_type" size="1" class="option2" >
          <option value="1800: Private">Private</option>
          <option value="3500: Corporate">Corporate</option>
          </select>
          <p>Corporate entries qualify for a tax donation certificate, please enquire via email.</p>

          <!-- HIDDEN FIELD - HONEYPOT ANTI_SPAM -->
          <input id="website" class="taken" name="cf_website" type="text"  />   
          <!-- END -->

          <!-- HIDDEN FIELD - CALCULATION -->
          <input id="cf_calculate" class="taken" value="1" name="cf_blank" type="text"  />   
          <!-- END -->

          <div class="box-contact"><span class="result">Amount Due: &nbsp;R</span><input type="text" name="cf_amount" readonly="readonly" value="1800" id="result">  

          <input name="Submit" class="submit" value="Submit" type="submit" />
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
$("select").change(function(){
      var val1 = +parseInt($("#cf_client_type").val());
      var val2 = +parseInt($("#cf_calculate").val());
      $("#result").val(val1*val2);
});
```

});

Comment: you simplify it `+$("#cf_client_type").val();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here is a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tsvv4/)

Set up your options with a `data-value` for your calculations and keep tha actual `value` for the text you want to pass along like so...

```
 <option value="Private" data-value="1800">Private</option>
 <option value="Corporate" data-value="3500">Corporate</option>
```

Then your script can be like this...

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $("select").change(function(){

     var val1 = +parseInt($("#cf_client_type").find('option:selected').attr('data-value'));
     var val2 = +parseInt($("#cf_calculate").val());
     $("#result").val(val1*val2);

  });

});
```

Comment: Add a data-value to the input fields for the integers you want and keep the actual form values as just the text you want and target the  data-value for your calculation.

Comment: Such as data-value="1800"

Comment: That should work i'll test it today thank you so much VIDesignz!! :D

Comment: @user2382274 Updated my answer, check out the fiddle as well!

Answer (score 0):

Replace the option value in your code to the following

Comment: <option value="1800: Private">Private</option>
 <option value="3500: Corporate">Corporate</option>

Comment: Replace the option value to the exact same one mentioned in my code?? :/